# Powershell stuck on connecting to pnponline when clicking form button

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

i try to connect the to pnponline after i click a button on the form.

After i click the button the powershell window hangs and nothing happens.

Anyone knows why? When i connect before the form is showing, everything is working fine.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.AutoSize = $true

$btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$btn.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,30)
$btn.Text = "Push me"
$btn.Add_Click({
    Write-Host "Before Connect"
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/xxxx" -UseWebLogin
    Write-Host "After Connect"
})
$form.Controls.Add($btn)

$form.ShowDialog()
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the click handler just tries to connect to a SharePoint site.. nothing more. There is no code following that.

Perhaps you would want the form to close after the connection is made and carry on with the script from where you now put `pause`, in that case, add `$form.Close()` directly beneath the `Connect-PnPOnline` line.

Something like:

```
$btn.Add_Click({
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/xxxx" -UseWebLogin
    $form.Close()
})
$form.Controls.Add($btn)

$form.ShowDialog()

# important, remove the form from memory when done with it
$form.Dispose()

# the rest of your sharepoint code goes here
```

Comment: Hi i edit the code above (its only to show the problem)

"Before Connect" is show but "After Connect" is never displayed.

Comment: @fug4zi Well, then the `Connect-PnPOnline` doesn't seem to work, stalls/hangs or whatever and you should investigate why that is.. Any error messages appear?

Comment: unfortunately no error message :( i opened a ticket now on https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/1329 maybe they knew why. With connect-azuread or connect-sposervice is working fine.

Comment: @fug4zi Ok, hope you'll get an answer there